# Change multiple lights

Tags: lighting

I am new to blender. I am trying to change the light strength on multiple lights. I cannot figure how to change them all at once. I see how to change objects, but not lights. Any tips out there?

Answer (score 2):

Select all your lights, go into the *Object Data* panel, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd> on the *Strength* or *Power* value, type the new value and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Or select all your lights, select the one you want to copy the strength from at last, and right click on its *Power* value > *Copy to Selected*.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is exactly what I was looking for. I did see the "Adjust Light Power" when I select all the lights and right click, but I see it adjust the lights from where they are initially set by the increase you change that selection to, but the change is only made by moving the mouse. I don't see where a keyboard input can be made with that option.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, could you please reformulate?

Comment: @Georgenikas where there's a slider that shows numbers you can either drag with the mouse or click on the number and type in a new value.  Does that help?

Comment: I just figured out how to use "Custom Properties" and add all my lights to that Custom Property and adjust them all at one time. I realize this is good only if I want a group of lights to have the same power. I was also able to use the "Custom Properties" to change all the light colors at the same time with one entry.